# Simplify the code using java 8 (with filter)

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

how can I simplify the code by using `filter`?.

```
return new LinkedList<>(pageNames.stream().map(ps -> {
           DocumentModel docModel = new DocumentModel();
           if (pages.contains(ps.getPageName())) {
               String pageName = ps.getPageName();
               docModel.setSopName(pageName);      
               docModel.setSopContent(pageApi.getPageContent(clientCode, pageName));
               docModel.setAverageRating(pageApi.getRating(clientCode, pageName));}
               return docModel;

        }).collect(toList()));
```

Comment: yes,, sorry typo i corrected now

Comment: This won't compile, because when the `if` condition is false, the `ps ->` lambda hasn't got a return.

Comment: Can you explain what your code does instead of just saying *"please simplify this for me*"?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do:

```
return pageNames.stream()
         .filter(ps -> pages.contains(ps.getPageName()))
         .map(ps -> {
               DocumentModel docModel = new DocumentModel();
               docModel.setSopName(ps.pageName());   
               docModel.setSopContent(pageApi.getPageContent(clientCode, ps.pageName))    
               return docModel;
           })
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

I am assuming you already know that *any local variables* used within the lambda expression *must* be *effectively final* or *final*.